# Linked objects between blender files does not transfer vertex groups

Tags: animation, objects, armature, vertex-groups, linked-data

Just modified a simple rig on a game character inside a "master" blend file with my character in T position. Had to add a vertex group after subdividing the spine bone.

[image: Here's my original master file. You can see spine_lower and spine_upper vertex groups and bones]

But when creating animation, I import-link that master character into another blend file. I've got everything in place, the subdivided bone, the geometry changes. But I'm surprised to see that the vertex groups aren't modified as well. They are present in the LINKED object that I can't modify, but not in the Duplicate Linked object I use for the animation.

[image: My linked file, can't touch that one]

Here is the Duplicate Linked one, which only get "spine" vertex group and not "spine_upper" and "spine_lower"

[image]

Comment: That's a known design limitation. VGroups are half belong to mesh data and object data. You just need to add a vertex group and properly rename it and then all weight values will be automatically added from linked source.

Comment: Okay, I've seen questions and posts from 2014 mentioning this. But I was thinking maybe the structure of the files had been revamped since to support this. 

Will try your solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay just tried it by renaming spine into spine_lower, but I can't "add" a vertex group to get spine_upper since it's a Duplicate Linked of an instance.. That's weird.

Comment: Try to unlink current data to say default cube and relink it again, might even work w/o messing with vgroups.

Comment: That worked ! 
Just clicked the little chain icon near the mesh name to make it local. Added the missing vertex group then linked it again. Seems to have worked this way. Thanks again for your help.